# Logging to the Application Insights TRACE event type using ILogger in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, ilogger

ASP.NET Core, targeting net7.0

I am using the .NET Core `ILogger` machinery to log messages to Application Insights.

I want to display application debug information, (I need to debug an app deployed to Azure). But ***I can't convince Application Insights NOT to filter out my logged debug messages.***

EDIT:

It seems to me that I am trying to get Application Insights to do something it's not designed to do - that is, consistently display ALL of a particular type of message. Is there a better way to log debug message in an app deployed to Azure?

END-OF-EDIT

I use what I think is the standard setup and usage pattern:

In Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

In my application code:

```
private readonly ILogger<MyCode> _logger;

/// <summary> DI constructor. </summary>
public MyCode(ILogger<MyApp.MyCode> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

// <summary> My method </summary>
public void MyMethod()
{
    _logger.LogDebug("My message");
}
```

In appsetings.json:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",

            "MyApp": "Trace"
        }
    }
}
```

**I *do* see my log output in the debug window**, so I know it's making its way through the `ILogger` machinery, presumably to all of the listeners. I assume the adaptive sampling scheme is filtering out my messages.

EDIT:

I've verified that calling `_logger.LogWarning` results in a "TRACE" message in ApplicationInsights. But I don't want to use `Warning` error level for debugging because there is no easy way to turn off the debug logging (e.g., in appsettings.json). I would need to modify the source code to remove the `warning`-level log messages.

Comment: Adaptive sampling works on operationId (or traceId in W3C terms) basis. I.e. it either samples in or out the entire transaction. Do you see a single debug trace? If not then it is most likely not adaptive sampling.

Comment: Your configuration snippet says Information and Warning. Debug is usually considered Verbose. Is it a valid setting in these two places?

Comment: @ZakiMa No, I don't see any `LogTrace` or `LogDebug` traces. If I change it to `LogWarning` then it shows up in App Insights. Is that telling me anything useful?

Comment: I think it tells that something doesn't plug debug level traces to Application Insights. Do you need historical data? Or Log Stream feature is sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Change `"LogLevel": { "Default": "Information"`, to `"Trace"`; or
2. Set `ApplicationInsights -> LogLevel -> Default` (see below); or
3. Change the log level in the code: `builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace);`; or
4. Log these "really important" messages as `Information` or even `Warning` - the problem with changing App Insight's log levels is that unless you get it right you'll get A LOT of other Debug+Trace messages not from your code. Don't worry about the word `Warning` - it's just a level.

[Create filter rules in configuration with appsettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#create-filter-rules-in-configuration-with-appsettingsjson) from

says:

> ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider is aliased as "ApplicationInsights". The following section of appsettings.json overrides the default LogLevel.Warning log level of Application Insights to log categories that start with "Microsoft" at level LogLevel.Error and higher.
>
> ```json
> {
>   "Logging": {
>     "LogLevel": {
>       "Default": "Warning"
>     },
>     "ApplicationInsights": {
>       "LogLevel": {
>         "Microsoft": "Error"
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: None of suggestions 1 through 3 has any effect on my problem. I already have a setting in appsettings.json that configures `ILogger` to pass along severity level `trace` and higher messages specifically from my app. I know this is working because I see the messages in the debug window.

Comment: And the problem with logging as Warning or Error is that then I can't easily filter out these debug messages using appsettings.json.

Comment: Note that I incorporated the above comments in the OP. I also added my observation that maybe I'm trying to use the wrong tool for debug logging. Application Insights just isn't designed to make that use case easy.